# Is this a dish or a metaphor ？

Tags: phrases, phrase-meaning

I read this sentence in a book：*Baileys flavoured squirty cream licked from a makeshift serving platter of hot, naked flesh.*

I was a little confused with *hot naked flesh*，is it referring to just some kind of meat or the human body? And what does *makeshift serving platter* mean？

And the context of the entire paragraph is：
*As a side note, whoever first uttered the phrase ‘nothing tastes as good as skinny feels’ had clearly never wrapped their chops around a full platter at Nandos. Or dry roasted peanuts. Or black bomber cheese. Or salted caramel flavoured Haagen Daz. Or Baileys flavoured squirty cream licked from a makeshift serving platter of hot, naked flesh.All of which I can state with some confidence, having been at various junctures throughout my life very thin and very hungry, taste better than skinny feels.*

Thank you for answering my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither a dish nor a metaphor. It seems to be quite literal.

The hot burning flesh refers to a living human being—or some part thereof.

The food referenced will be more familiar in Great Britain than the U.S.

It’s from a book called A Beginner’s Guide to Being Mental, by Natasha Devon. Although this selection verges on being soft-core porn, the book overall is a self-help book on mental illness. The quote is about anorexia.

Answer (score 0):

Baileys flavoured squirty cream licked from a makeshift serving platter of hot, naked flesh

The fact that they are calling it *Bailey's cream* tells us it is an actual food brand and not (likely) that of the boyfriend, Bailey. From how they tell it such a cream would be delicious anywhere but would be even better if served on hot, naked flesh.

The point is just how much they enjoy good food. The list they give has as its crescendo the serving of the richest of substances on the skin of your basic virgin sacrifice. I'd be all for it, but then I'm on Atkins.

Comment: [Bailey's Irish Cream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baileys_Irish_Cream) is an alcoholic liqueur based on cream, cocoa and Irish whiskey, invented in 1971 by a team of consultants on behalf of Gilbeys (Ireland). Rumour has it they were fooling around with condensed milk and whiskey and came up with something that 'didn't taste punishing'. It has inspired lots of imitators (you can't copyright the word 'cream') such as Welsh Cream, etc.  These drinks are sometimes stigmatized as 'women's drinks' and many people find them too sweet or sickly.

Comment: "The point is just how much they enjoy good food." to me, the point is that they have an eating disorder. Also, a strong whiff of obsession, which fits with the theme of the book.